# [UPDATE]How do I access values from the json object?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am completely new to android & JSON.
Please help me out to find a solution for this problem--
Below is my php code.

```
    <?php 
require "conn.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['mailid']))
{
    $mailid = $_POST['mailid'];
    $today="2017-05-05";//date('Y-m-d');
    $mysql_qry = "select employee_id from employee where employee_email='$mailid';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $emp_id=$row['employee_id'];
    if($emp_id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) from task where employee_id='$emp_id' and task_date='$today';";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);
        $row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        if($result1) 
        {
            $taskcount['count']= $row2['count(*)'];
            $taskquery = "select task_name from task where employee_id='$emp_id' and task_date='$today';";
            $restask_name=mysqli_query($conn ,$taskquery);

            for($i=0;$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($restask_name);$i++)
            {
                $task_name[]= $row1[0];
            }
            $taskname['tasks']=$task_name;
            $array=array_merge($taskcount,$taskname);
            echo json_encode($array);
        }
        else 
        {
        echo json_encode($taskcount);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "employee ID doesnt match!!";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "post variables are not set";
}
?>
```

I am getting a response from server like below--

```
{
 "count": "4",
 "tasks": [
        "collect paper",
        "krishna",
        "mys",
        "bng"   ] 
}
```

My code to parse json object is as follows--

```
if (!result.equals("employee ID doesnt match!!") || !result.equals("post variables are not set")) {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                    MAX_ROWS = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("count"));
                    System.out.println("rows:"+MAX_ROWS);
                    JSONArray tasks = json.getJSONArray("tasks");
                    for (int task_id = 0; task_id < MAX_ROWS; task_id++) {
                        taskname[task_id] = tasks.getString(task_id);//**LINE 153**
                        System.out.println(taskname[task_id]);
                    }

                }
```

Now I m getting an Null Pointer Exception,Here is my Stacktrace--

```
05-05 17:41:33.255 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker.ViewtaskActivity$BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(ViewtaskActivity.java:153)
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker.ViewtaskActivity$BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(ViewtaskActivity.java:107)
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-05 17:41:33.396 22823-23024/com.example.anusha.fieldworkemployeetracker W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How can I do that? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: put your actual json response here

Comment: you are getting any error on this?

Comment: @BhupatBheda {"count":["4"],"tasks0":["collect paper"],"tasks1":["krishna"],"tasks2":["mys"],"tasks3":["bng"]} 
my JSON response

Comment: "tasks[0]"... are json arrays not objects.

Comment: @SachinGupta My php code is working fine. I m even getting a Valid response.I just need to parse my json object in android.

Comment: @CAAnusha Why not you put **All Tasks in Single JSON Array**, anyway its up-to your requirement. For your current question Refer **R.P.M & Sachin Gupta** answer.

Comment: @Yugesh thank you for your suggestion!!

Comment: Null Pointer Exception is giving for **taskname[]**. Can you provide declaration of  **taskname[]**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
if (!result.equals("employee ID doesnt match!!") || !result.equals("post variables are not set")) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

              int  MAX_ROWS = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("count"));
                System.out.println("rows:"+MAX_ROWS);
                String taskname[] = new String[MAX_ROWS];
                JSONArray tasks = json.getJSONArray("tasks");
                for (int task_id = 0; task_id < MAX_ROWS; task_id++) {
                    taskname[task_id] = tasks.getString(task_id);
                    System.out.println(tasks.getString(task_id));
                }

            }
```

Comment: this is where i was going wrong!
thank you so much..Now everything is working fine:)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
if (!result.equals("employee ID doesnt match!!") || !result.equals("post variables are not set")) {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                    //JSONObject count = json.getJSONObject("task" + task_id);
                    JSONArray count = json.getJSONArray("count");
                    MAX_ROWS = Integer.parseInt(count.getString(0));
                    System.out.println("rows:" + MAX_ROWS);
                    for (int task_id = 0; task_id < MAX_ROWS; task_id++) {
                        JSONArray task = json.getJSONArray("task" + String.valueOf(task_id));
                        taskname[task_id] = task.getString(0);
                        System.out.println(taskname[task_id]);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: now i m able to retrieve MAX_ROWS but not my task_name

Comment: is there any exception? had you tried my updated code? I have edited my code

Comment: I m getting NullPointerException

Comment: Ok use following code before for loop:

taskname = new String[MAX_ROWS];

Comment: @CAAnusha are you declare `taskname[]` with array size?. May be you are facing NPE on `taskname[]`

Answer (score 0):

make Json like ;

```
       { "count": 
            "4"
          ,
          "tasks0": 
            "collect paper"
          ,
          "tasks1": 
            "krishna"
          ,
          "tasks2": 
            "mys"
          ,
          "tasks3": 
            "bng"
}
```

Then To parse above JSON use following code;

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResponseString);
  String countValue = json.getString("count");
```

Comment: I tried. I m not getting the format that you specified.
would you be able to tell me where i m going wrong in my php code??

Comment: $taskcount['count']= array($row2['count(*)']);

remove `array()` from above code & same do with **task**

Comment: Is this JSON is correct??
{
  "count": "4",
  "tasks0": "collect paper",
  "tasks1": "krishna",
  "tasks2": "mys",
  "tasks3": "bng"
}

Comment: Yes, Its called JSONObject. For more information see this ; https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: But how to access my tasks??

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code:

1. Here you are trying to access JSONArray, using the code of `JSONObject`.
   E.g.: `count` is `JSONArray`. So you should parse it as `JSONArray`.
   like this:

   ```
   MAX_ROWS = json.getJSONArray("count").getInt(0);
   ```
2. key name is tasks in JSONObject, you should use proper name for that.

   ```
   JSONArray tasks = json.getJSONArray("tasks" + task_id);
   ```
3. `task_name` is also a `JSONArray`, so you should handle that accordingly.

So working code should be like this:

```
MAX_ROWS = json.getJSONArray("count").getInt(0);
for (int task_id = 0; task_id < MAX_ROWS; task_id++) {
     JSONArray tasks = json.getJSONArray("tasks" + task_id);
     taskname[task_id] = task.getString("task_name");
     System.out.println(taskname[task_id]);
}
```

Comment: I am getting Null Pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
MAX_ROWS = json.getJSONArray("count").getInt(0);
System.out.println("rows:" + MAX_ROWS);
for (int task_id = 0; task_id < MAX_ROWS; task_id++) {
    JSONArray task = json.getJSONArray("tasks" + task_id);
    taskname[task_id] = task.getString(0);
    System.out.println(taskname[task_id]);
}
```

However I think there is a more structural problem with your JSON String, which makes it difficult to parse into an object. Namely you're storing everything as a JSONArray (instead of their actual types, e.g. int or String).

Personally I would consider structuring the json like so:

```
{
   "count":4,
   "tasks":[
      "collect paper",
      "do Something else",
      "learn about json",
      "learn about gson"
   ]
}
```

That way you could simply (de)serialize it with a library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)
using the following POJO:

```
public class TaskHolder {

@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private Integer count;
@SerializedName("tasks")
@Expose
private List<String> tasks = null;

public Integer getCount() {
return count;
}

public void setCount(Integer count) {
this.count = count;
}

public List<String> getTasks() {
return tasks;
}

public void setTasks(List<String> tasks) {
this.tasks = tasks;
}

}
```

That way it's a lot easier (imho) to manipulate the data and pass it back and forth.
Good luck!

Comment: thank you!
{
  "count": "4",
  "tasks": [
    "collect paper",
    "krishna",
    "mys",
    "bng"
  ]
}
is this what you wanted my JSON object to look like??

Comment: welcome, and it's only a recommendation, but yeah that's what I would do! Also note that it should be `"count": 4` (without the quotes around the 4) so that the json deserialiser can understand that it is a number. This way you can deserialize it into the object shown in my initial answer (i.e. TaskHolder, using e.g. the gson library) or get it from the JsonObject using `getInt("count")`.

Answer (score 0):

Before directly go straightforward understand what is json and how we use in android.

for Json you know there are tow brackets first one is '[ ]' which is display as Json Array and another one is '{ }' which display Json Object, So if you want to parse data from json object then its difficulty if you perfectly understand structure of json data,

Here is the example which will explain you json parsing

```
String jsonData="{"data":["a","b","c"]}";
```

Now if you want to access a then just structure, First one is Object so create JSON Object and put string in Argument.

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(jsonData);
```

Second one is array so you need to put inside as array, JSONObject and JSONArray Object also provide some defual method which will help to parse data,

JSONArray jsonArray=json.getJsonArray(postion); //postion 1 for 'a'
String finalData=jsonArray.getString(0);

Now then after try for your code,

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                    MAX_ROWS = json.getJSONArray("count").getInt(0);
                    System.out.println("rows:" + MAX_ROWS);
                    for (int task_id = 0; task_id < MAX_ROWS; task_id++) {
                        JSONObject task = json.getJSONArray("task" + task_id);
                        taskname[task_id] = task.getString(0);
                        System.out.println(taskname[task_id]);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider your json response as a String result, and use following code to parse the json

```
String result = "{\"count\": [\"4\"],\"tasks0\": [\"collect paper\"],\"tasks1\": [\"krishna\"],\"tasks2\": [\"mys\"],\"tasks3\": [\"bng\"]}";
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
            String countString = json.getJSONArray("count").optString(0, "default_value");
            int MAX_ROWS = Integer.parseInt(countString);

            for (int task_id = 0; task_id < MAX_ROWS; task_id++) {
                String taskString = json.getJSONArray("tasks" + task_id).optString(0, "default_value");
                Log.d("Task Names", taskString);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```